# loading fstreams into a std::vector in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, fstream

This is a simple and complex question at the same time.

This compiles:

```
int Test;
vector<int> TEST;
TEST.push_back(Test);
cout << TEST.size();
```

This does not compile:

```
fstream Test;
vector<fstream> TEST;
TEST.push_back(Test);
cout << TEST.size();
```

Is there any particular reason?
Is there a way for me to get a dynamic list of fstreams?

The error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vector_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  vector_test.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\fstream(1347): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(176) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: In C++, this will become possible: IOStreams are movable, and vector will support movable types.

Comment: @MSalters: A reference to the part of the C++11 standard which states the above might be helpful ;-)

Comment: @FrankH. : ["Pretty much all of Section 27"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066691/is-stdofstream-movable), to quote Howard Hinnant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The object `fstream` is not copyable.

If you need to record `fstream`s in a `vector` you can declare a `std::vector<std::fstream*>` and push back the address of the object. Remember that if you save the pointer, then you must ensure that, when you access it, the object is still alive.

Comment: An object doesn't have to be copyable to be moved into a container: this was a C++ 2003 restriction. It is sufficient for the type to be movable but you need to use an object which can be moved from, e.g. either a temporary or the result of `std::move()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl good to know. I must definitely start learning C++11

Comment: Also, `emplace_back` into `vector<ifstream>` works fine in VS2013. (Though fails in GCC.)

Answer (score 9):

In C++ 2011 the concrete stream objects are movable. Howver, to take advantage of this you either need to pass a temporary or allow the object to be moved:

```
std::vector<std::ofstream> files;
files.push_back(std::ofstream("f1"));
std::ofstream file("f2");
files.push_back(std::move(file));
```

Note that you can't use the `file` variable after this as the stream was moved into `files`.

Answer (score 3):

To use a class with a vector, it must be copyable. `fstream` is not.

See: [C++ std::ifstream in constructor problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847611/c-stdifstream-in-constructor-problem)

**Edit:** If you need to have multiple references to the same fstream, you can use shared_ptr to manage them. Try something like:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<fstream> > TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic requirement for a type to be pushed into vector is that the object should be copyable, `fstream` is not copyable and hence you get compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, `fstream` is not copyable. You could just do:

```
vector<fstream> TEST;
TEST.push_back(fstream()); //fstream is created in the vector, no copy needed
```

And use like this:

```
fstream& A = TEST[0];
```

And even iterate like this:

```
for(fstream& S : TEST){
...
}
```